# 'ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'

Tags: c#, json, generics, arraylist, task

I'm getting multiple errors. As I'm new to this async/await process. So with little research I've done this bit:-

I've a function like:-

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetMultipleTblResult(AdminBundle aBundleFetch)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(aBundleFetch.ListType) && aBundleFetch.ListType.Equals(Constants.Board))
        {
            ArrayList MainList = new ArrayList();

            aBundleFetch.ListType = Constants.Board;
            Func<ArrayList> functionBoard = new Func<ArrayList>(() => FetchTableDataAsync(aBundleFetch)); // Getting Error (Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.ArrayList>>' to 'System.Collections.ArrayList')
            ArrayList resBoard = await Task.Factory.StartNew<ArrayList>(functionBoard);

            aBundleFetch.ListType = Constants.Classes;
            Func<ArrayList> functionClass = new Func<ArrayList>(() => FetchTableDataAsync(aBundleFetch)); // Getting Error (Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.ArrayList>>' to 'System.Collections.ArrayList')
            ArrayList resClass = await Task.Factory.StartNew<ArrayList>(functionClass);

            aBundleFetch.ListType = Constants.ClassSubject;
            Func<ArrayList> functionClassSubject = new Func<ArrayList>(() => FetchTableDataAsync(aBundleFetch)); // Getting Error (Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.ArrayList>>' to 'System.Collections.ArrayList')
            ArrayList resClassSubject = await Task.Factory.StartNew<ArrayList>(functionClassSubject);

            aBundleFetch.ListType = Constants.ClassMaterial;
            Func<ArrayList> functionClassMaterial = new Func<ArrayList>(() => FetchTableDataAsync(aBundleFetch)); // Getting Error (Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.ArrayList>>' to 'System.Collections.ArrayList')
            ArrayList resClassMaterial = await Task.Factory.StartNew<ArrayList>(functionClassMaterial);


            MainList.Add(resBoard);
            MainList.Add(resClass);
            MainList.Add(resClassSubject);
            MainList.Add(resClassMaterial);

            var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(MainList);

            return new JsonResult { Data = json, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
        else
            return new JsonResult { Data = "", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

From my FetchTableDataAsync function I want to return a List of arraylists and send them over to GetMultipleTblResult :-

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ArrayList>> FetchTableDataAsync(AdminBundle abundleList)
    {
        AdminBundle abundle = new AdminBundle();
        string innerMesage = string.Empty;
        if (Session["AdminBundle"] != null)
            abundle = (AdminBundle)Session["AdminBundle"];

        ArrayList BulkList = null;
        abundle.ListType = abundleList.ListType;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(abundleList.ListType))
        {
            using (SMContext db = new SMContext())
            {
                switch (abundleList.ListType)
                {
                    case "Category":
                        List<Category> CategoryList = null;
                        CategoryList = db.CatObj.Where(x => x.Status_Info == Constants.StatusInfoOne).ToList();
                        BulkList.Add(CategoryList);
                        break;
                    //Class Starts
                    case "Board":
                        List<Board> BoardList = null;
                        BoardList = db.BoardObj.Where(x => x.Status_Info == Constants.StatusInfoOne).ToList();
                        BulkList.Add(BoardList);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                        //Main default Ends
                }
            }
        }

        return await BulkList; //Getting Error 'ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'ArrayList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    }
```

Basically I want to return set of multiple lists asynchronously from later function(FetchTableDataAsync) to previous function(GetMultipleTblResult) and then pass it to my angular.js file in JSON format.

**EDIT:**

So with help of @JohnWu I've done this bit:-

```
    [HttpPost]
    [LogInFilter]
    public JsonResult GetMultipleTblResult(AdminBundle aBundleFetch)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(aBundleFetch.ListType) && aBundleFetch.ListType.Equals(Constants.Board))
        {
            Task<AllTblListClass> AllTblObj = GetTableDataAsync(aBundleFetch);

            //var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            //var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(AllTblObj);

            return new JsonResult { Data = "", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
        else
            return new JsonResult { Data = "", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }

    public async Task<AllTblListClass> GetTableDataAsync(AdminBundle abundleList)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(abundleList.ListType) && abundleList.ListType.Equals(Constants.Board))
        {
            return new AllTblListClass
            {
                BoardObj = await FetchBoardsAsync(),
                ClsObj = await FetchClassAsync(),
                ClsSubObj = await FetchClassSubAsync(),
                MatTypeObj = await FetchMaterialTAsync(),
                ClassSubMatRelationObj = await FetchClassSubMatRelAsync()
            };

        }

        else
        {
            return new AllTblListClass { };
        }
    }

    public async Task<List<ClassSubMatRelation>> FetchClassSubMatRelAsync()
    {
        using (SMContext db = new SMContext())
        {
            return await Task<List<ClassSubMatRelation>>.Run(() => db.ClassSubMatRelationObj.Where(x => x.Status_Info == Constants.StatusInfoOne).ToList()); // It executes untill here and then sleeps for endless time.
        }
    } //I'm not writing all functions as it will create a long question
```

But on this line of code:-

```
return await Task<List<ClassSubMatRelation>>.Run(() => db.ClassSubMatRelationObj.Where(x => x.Status_Info == Constants.StatusInfoOne).ToList());
```

The execution sleeps and nothing happens. There isn't any Error or Exception generating.

Comment: Please please don't use `ArrayList` - there are almost no cases where that should be used, and it makes code virtually unreadable

Comment: @MarcGravell then I should replace it with? And Which Error?

Comment: I don’t know what “sleeps” mean. I suggest describing the symptoms (not a preliminary conclusion.)

Comment: Also, what sort of program is this? You need to aware that different types of applications have different types of synchronization context, some of which can deadlock if you aren’t careful.

Comment: Means the code isn't executing after that..

Answer (score 2):

From the end of your second method:

```
return await BulkList;
```

Here, `BulkList` is declared as `ArrayList`. There is no need for this method to be `async` or involve `Task<T>` in any way, so the most appropriate option is simply to remove all the `async` and `Task` from that method. If you *need* to expose it as a `Task<T>` - `Task.FromResult` may be of use, but it is sub-optimal.

Comment: thanks @marc but I need to execute this method in parallel

Comment: `BulkList` is not a method. It is an instance of ArrayList. You can't execute an instance.

Comment: @Deepak async and parallel are separate (but tangentially related) topics. It doesn't need to be async/task to be parallelized

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want a single function to return either a list of categories or a list of boards. If boards and categories are not related (e.g. they do not share a common interface), then this is a questionable design. How is the caller going to call it? The caller at some point has to know the difference, and the developer has to know in order to put the list into something type-specific so the objects can be read. If the caller knows the difference anyway, why not use two separate functions? For example

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Category>> FetchCategoriesAsync(AdminBundle abundleList)
{
    if (abundleList.ListType != "Category") throw new ArgumentException("abundleList");
    AdminBundle abundle = Session["AdminBundle"] as AdminBundle;
    abundle.ListType = abundleList.ListType;

    using (SMContext db = new SMContext())
    {
        return await Task<List<Category>>.Run( () => db.CatObj.Where(x => x.Status_Info == Constants.StatusInfoOne).ToList());
    }
}
```

Notice in this example the `db` call is wrapped in a task and awaited. This will give you the asynchronicity that you are looking for (a method can't act async unless there is an await inside it somewhere).

If you want to be able to get categories and boards at the same time, you can implement a wrapper function on top of it, like this:

```
class TableData
{
    public List<Catgeory> Categories { get; set; }       
    public List<Boards> Boards { get; set; }
}

public async Task<TableData> GetTableDataAsync(AdminBundle abundleList)
{
    return new TableData
    {
        Categories = await FetchCategoriesAsync(abundleList),            
        Boards = await FetchBoardsAsync(abundleList);
    };
}
```

Comment: Great!! With this answer you understood my point completely! Will try this and get back to you shortly.

Comment: with the first part actually I've around 20 tables. Making seperate function for each table will be very lenghty isn't it?

Comment: You could use a generic method if your domain objects share an interface. Otherwise, if you want strongly-typed results, you need to have specific return types and specific functions.

Comment: Thanks @John can you share an example?

Comment: Also shouldn't this Task<IEnumerable<Category>> FetchCategoriesAsync be this Task<List<Category>> FetchCategoriesAsync

Comment: You can change the signature if you want, but I would suggest keeping the ToList call. Otherwise you could run into issues with object disposal.

Comment: Wrapping db call in Task.Run is bad advice. Most (correctly implemented) database api libraries has methods to execute database queries asynchronously (it a way that does not involve using thread pool threads, like `Task.Run` does). For example, if `SMContext` is Entity Framework context (looks like it) - there is `ToListAsync()` extension method.

Comment: @JohnWu Please see the modified question.